# How can I check if a char is empty in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to test if a property is empty or not. It's declared like this in my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic) char nextOperation;
```

And in the .m file:

```
@synthesize nextOperation;
```

Correct me if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm pretty new in this world.

In a method I have to test if nextOperation has anything on it. If true (`YES`?) I should do something, and after that assign a new value to that property.

I've tried `nextOperation == ''`, `empty`, `isEmpty`, `isempty`, and everything throws me an Xcode warning/error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A char can not be empty. A char is a scalar value just like an int - just a little smaller (usually 8 bit). You might want to compare it to `0` or `0x00` for your purpose.

e.g.

```
if (!self.nextOperation)
{
    //empty nextOperation
}
else
{
    //we got something in nextOperation
}
```

Comment: crap, I forgot that in objective-C you don't have empty values, only default ones. thanks for the remind!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (self.nextOperation == 0) {
    // it's empty
}
```

or simply

```
if (!self.nextOperation) {
}
```

When you declare a property like that (without explicitly declaring an ivar or using `@synthesize`) you can access the property using the dot syntax (`self.property`) or use the automatically generated ivar that starts with an underscore (`_property`).